# With VBA how to use CountIfs with a variable

Tags: excel, excel-2007, vba

I cannot find an example anywhere of using CountIfs with a variable. Why is this giving an "Object Requried" error?

```
Dim recTable As ListObject
Dim EOM As Date
Dim Pending As Double

For x = 1 To RecordCount
    If Not IsNull(recTable.DataBodyRange(x, 7).Value) Then
                    Pending = Pending + WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(recTable.DataBodyRange(x, 2).Value, "<=" & EOM, recTable.DataBodyRange(x, 7).Value, ">" & EOM)
                ElseIf IsNull(recTable.DataBodyRange(x, 7).Value) And Not IsNull(recTable.DataBodyRange(x, 6).Value) Then
                    Pending = Pending + Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(recTable.DataBodyRange(x, 2).Value, "" <= "" & EOM, recTable.DataBodyRange(x, 6).Value, "" > "" & EOM)
                Else
                    Pending = Pending + 1
            End If
        Debug.Print Pending
Next x
```

Comment: You do not need the your  two double quotes should be single double quotes `"" <= ""` should be `"<="`

Comment: Okay made that change, however, I still get an "Object Required" error.

Comment: Did you also change `"" > ""` to `">"`?

Comment: Yes, here is the line: WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(recTable.DataBodyRange(x, 2).Value, "<=" & EOM, recTable.DataBodyRange(x, 7).Value, ">" & EOM)

Comment: The first and third criteria of COUNTIFS() are ranges and not specific values.  You do not loop when using COUNTIFS() you merely set the entire range.

Comment: Are you assigning that **to** something?  And why bother using a CountIfs - you could just use `If recTable.DataBodyRange(x, 2).Value <= EOM And recTable.DataBodyRange(x, 7).Value > EOM Then` `Pending = Pending + 1` `End If`

Comment: Yes, I am assigning it to another variable name "Pending." [Pending = Pending + 'the line above']

Comment: It would be helpful if you would revise your question to include the *current* state of your code, including necessary variable declarations, etc. Currently, question is a bit lacking...

Comment: I've edited my previous comment to use `Pending` instead of `xxxx`.  If you really are just trying to use the `CountIfs` function on single values, that would be the way to do it.  If you want to do a `CountIfs` over a range of values then, as @Scott Craner said, you need to pass the range to be looked at.

Comment: @David I've edited to include the current state.

Comment: @YowE3K your suggestion will meet my need, I will just use the If Then and count the single values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on comments, I recommend the following:

```
Dim recTable As ListObject
Dim EOM As Date
Dim Pending As Double ' Maybe Long or Integer?

'recTable is not set in the posted code, but I assume it is in the actual code
'EOM is not set in the posted code, but I assume it is in the actual code
'RecordCount is not declared or set in the posted code, but I assume it is in the actual code
'x is not declared in the posted code, but I assume it is in the actual code

With recTable
    For x = 1 To RecordCount
        If Not IsNull(.DataBodyRange(x, 7).Value) Then
            If .DataBodyRange(x, 2).Value <= EOM And _
               .DataBodyRange(x, 7).Value > EOM Then
                Pending = Pending + 1
            End If
        ElseIf Not IsNull(.DataBodyRange(x, 6).Value) Then
            If .DataBodyRange(x, 2).Value <= EOM And _
               .DataBodyRange(x, 6).Value > EOM The
                Pending = Pending + 1
            End If
        Else
            Pending = Pending + 1
        End If
        Debug.Print Pending
    Next x
End With
```